# Redirect to error page from ajax call in ASP.net MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

In a MVC app with an error page `Error.cshtml` located in the Shared folder, how to redirect on this page in case on error returned by the ajax call ?

```
$.ajax({
    //Some stuff here...
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location = "???????";
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to redirect to a controller method that returns your `Error.cshtml` view

Comment: That's what I tought, thanks Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add your controller name followed by your action name - like this `/[ErrorController]/[ErrorActionName]` this might solve your issue - Thanks

Don't forget the forward slash

Answer (score 0):

Just use `@Url.Action()` helper to create the URL string from controller name and action name:

```
$.ajax({
    // Some stuff here
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        window.location = '@Url.Action("ErrorActionName", "ErrorControllerName")';
    }
}
```

This is more favored way because the forward slash will be generated automatically by the helper method.